# Execute a function at a later time in PyQt6

Tags: python, event-handling, pyqt6

Is there a minimal overhead way of calling a custom function in my main window at a later time, similar to how an event would be called later when triggered by a call to postEvent()?

While it's easy to find info on triggering predefined events ad hoc, it's not clear how to quickly set up a custom event function that can be called this way. It's also not clear to me how the default implementation of some class's event() function maps from QEvent subclass to knowing what actual function must be called to process that event.

Since the function and its initiation will be at the same level, inside the same class, I'm not really looking for a signal/slot solution. I'm hoping I don't have to resort to creating a QEvent subclass, but if this is the cleanest way, I'll do that, I just don't know how to hook everything up.

Comment: Call what function? And why QTimer is not an option?

Comment: A do_something function that I want to put some code into. QTimer could work, but it seems like overkill and will make my code less readable. There's no actual time that I want it to execute, just not right now in a blocking way.

Comment: Creating a custom event is possible, but it would probably be unnecessary, especially if you don't need event propagation. If you just want to pospone a function call after the current event queue is cleared up, just use `QTimer.singleShot(0, function)`. If readability is that an issue, you can use a global basic lambda: `postpone = lambda func: QTimer.singleShot(0, func)` and then simply do `postpone(do_something)` wherever you need it. In any case, if you clarify what you need this for, we may provide more comprehensive answers.

Comment: That's actually a pretty cool solution. Generally, what I need it for is for execution that doesn't hold up whoever is calling it. Specifically (though I don't think this is the last use case I'll encounter), I'm responding to a "on-drop" event to have my app do something with files dragged in Windows from, say an Explorer window. I notice that while the files are being processed, the Explorer window is unresponsive. My own UI is not unresponsive, because I have periodic processEvents() calls (and all the checks and balances required to do that safely).

Comment: Well, that seems like an interesting case... Which you should've explained that since the beginning. I strongly suggest to take your time, rephrase your question including a more comprehensive explanation of the a above and a valid and clear [mre], then [edit] your post in order to explain all that.

Comment: While the specific issue prompted me to ask the question here, it's the general solution that I'd say I'm after, but I'll rephrase shortly.